# Unity: How to find all neighbors recursively (neighbors of neighbors)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, recursion, stack-overflow, nearest-neighbor

I'm making a Bubble Shooter game in Unity. I came to the point where I can hit another bubble and it destroys all of its neighbors.

Now I'm trying to destroy all of its neighbors' neighbors and it causes a stack overflow. I was using a recursion.

I did it without the recursion, and found its second-tier neighbors just to see if the logic works out. It does. The problem is with the way I'm using a recursion.

```
    private List<Bubble> FindAllRecursiveNeighbors(Vector2Int originPosition)
{
    List<Bubble> allNeighbors = FindNeighbors(originPosition);

    List<Bubble> result = new List<Bubble>();

    foreach (Bubble bubble in allNeighbors)
    {
        if (result.Contains(bubble)) { continue; }
        result.Add(bubble);
    }

    // Recursion starts here.
    foreach (Bubble bubble in result)
    {
        List<Bubble> neighbors = FindAllRecursiveNeighbors(FindPositionOfBubble(bubble));
        foreach (Bubble neighbor in neighbors)
        {
            if (result.Contains(neighbor)) { continue; }
            result.Add(neighbor);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

I expected all the bubbles in a line to be destroyed. I got the stack overflow error. If I delete the recursive part it works, but just for the immediate neighbors.

The error is this: StackOverflowException: The requested operation caused a stack overflow, and it is in the line where I'm calling the FindAllRecursiveNeighbors again.

Comment: I've rolled-back your last edit: there's no need to put [solved] on your question - the system already shows solved questions differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern is correct. I believe stack overflow exception is caused by returning to an already visited node.

You might want to keep a list of already visited nodes and then don't return them as neighbors. You already have what is needed and it only needs to be rigged up. The code bellow might work for you

```
private List<Bubble> FindAllRecursiveNeighbors(Vector2Int originPosition, List<Bubble> result = null)
{
    List<Bubble> allNeighbors = FindNeighbors(originPosition);

    if (result == null)
        // Mark (see bellow)
        result = new List<Bubble>();

    var newBubbles = new List<Bubble>();
    foreach (Bubble bubble in allNeighbors)
    {
        if (!result.Contains(bubble))
        {
            result.Add(bubble);
            newBubbles.Add(bubble);
        }
    }

    // Recursion starts here.
    foreach (Bubble bubble in newBubbles)
    {
        List<Bubble> neighbors = FindAllRecursiveNeighbors(FindPositionOfBubble(bubble), result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

One thing was not clear for me though. Check out where I marked in the code. There you should add current node to list if your `FindNeighbors` function doesn't return the current node.

As final explanation what happens here is this:
Lets suppose you have 3 nodes like this 1 <-> 2 <-> 3
Now you start with 1 and go to check neighbors of 2 you find 3 and also 1 again you go again in the loop to check out the neighbors of 1 and this cycle continues.

The best method to tackle such task is to have a list of unsearched nodes and pick from that with little recursion. But, here I kept a list of already visited nodes, which can get heavy depending on the number of nodes you want to explode in a single operation. But this is less change to your original code.

Comment: Wow, thank you @Emad ! How do I do that? I've been looking at the code and recursion is really confusing to me . . .

Comment: thank you so much, I just c/p your code and it works perfectly now! I have no idea what you did, but I'll mark your answer as correct. Also I don't understand the mark. . .
Again, thank you again so much, I've been wrecking my head with this for days and now it works somehow :)